# Dog person and cat person

Tags: nouns

Does "dog person" just mean "someone who likes dog as a pet"?

Or does it have any other connotation?

Comment: Might be.  Or might be something else.  You'd need to determine what from the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A "dog person" is someone who likes dogs and usually keeps one or more as a pet. Sometimes the connotation can be "one or the other"; i. e., "Are you a 'dog person' or a 'cat person'?" To which I would reply, "I'm both a dog person and a cat person, and I love them both!"